# Dispersion plots in R

Tags: r, plot, text-mining

I am facing the following problem.
I have 12 texts and I need to create a dispersion plot for which one of them. I want R to display several dispersion plots together. Right now I have all the information that I need and I am able to create individual dispersion plots. I just don't know how to plot all of them together, as explained here (https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html). Here is my code:

```
    input.dir<-"corpus"
    files.v<-dir(input.dir, "\\.txt$")

    make.file.word.v.l<-function(files.v, input.dir){
  text.word.vector.l<-list()
  for(i in 1:length(files.v)){
    text.v <- scan(paste(input.dir, files.v[i], sep="/"), what="character", sep="\n")
    Encoding(text.v)<-"UTF-8"
    text.v <- paste(text.v, collapse=" ")
    text.lower.v <- tolower(text.v)
    text.words.v <- strsplit(text.lower.v, "\\W")
    text.words.v <- unlist(text.words.v)
    text.words.v <- text.words.v[which(text.words.v!="")]
    text.word.vector.l[[files.v[i]]] <- text.words.v
  }
  return(text.word.vector.l)
}

corpus.l<-make.file.word.v.l(files.v, input.dir)
```

This list contains all the texts.

This contains all "times":

```
tiempo <- function(corpus.l){
  tiempo.l<-list()
  for (i in 1:length(corpus.l)){
    time<-seq(1:length(corpus.l[[i]]))
    tiempo.l[[files.v[i]]]<-time
  }
  return(tiempo.l)
}

tiempo.l<-tiempo(corpus.l)


hits<-function(keyword){
  hits.l<-list()
  for (i in 1:length(corpus.l)) {
    hits.v<-which(corpus.l[[i]]==keyword)
    hits.keyword.v<-rep(NA, length(tiempo.l[[i]]))
    hits.keyword.v[hits.v]<-1
    hits.l[[files.v[i]]]<-hits.keyword.v
  }
  return(hits.l)
}

noches.todos<-hits("noches")

plot(noches.todos[[1]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
```

I have 12 books and I want to plot all of the 12 dispersion plots together, at the same time, so I can compare them. I believe it is possible, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. All you need to do is set par:

```
par(mfrow =c(4,3))
options(scipen=5)
plot(noches.todos[[1]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[2]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[3]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[4]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[5]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[6]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[7]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[8]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[9]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[10]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[11]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
plot(noches.todos[[12]], main="Dispersion plot",
     xlab="time", ylab="keyword", type="h", ylim=c(0,1), yaxt='n')
```

You also use options(scipen) to avoid scientific notation.
I couldn't make R plot in a single column all my plots, but I was able to get a good image. There may be a limit for the graphical display of rows. The first number in mfrow (in my case 4) set the numbers of rows, and the second (in my case 3) the number of columns. This means you will get 3 plots for each row, meaning 12 graphs.